# Excel formatação Condicional

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma duvida e gostaria de saber se é possível uma vez que não estou a conseguir.

Eu tenho uma célula que me mostra um resultado (Célula D4)
E quero que com o resultado ele me sublinhe dois linhas.

Exemplo:
Se a celula D4 for igual a "G4" Sublinha a linha X

Se a celula D4 for igual a "G6" Sublinha a linha Y

Eu coloquei esta regra e não está a funcionar:
=SE($D$4="G$";"")

Comment: Acho não seja possível usando fórmulas, tu teria que construir uma macro em VBA.

Comment: construir uma macro só para mostrar uns dados a sublinhar?

Comment: Não queria usar Macro por nunca ter estudado isso. Mas estou a ver que so tenho essa forma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer duas regras de formatação condicional separadas:

[image: A3 diferente de 1]

[image: A3 igual a 1]

No seu caso, substitua `=$A$3<>1` e `=$A$3=1` por `=$D$4=$G$4` e `=$D$4=$G$6`